# Save Numpy confusion matrix in human readable text with labels

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am not super familiar with numpy but I am using it to calculate a confusion matrix at which it is fantastic other than the fact that it doesn't print the labels on the x and y axis.  since my data labels aren't always the same it is a pain to go back and check in which order they were given.  Right now I am using:

Right now I am using:

```
true_val = [int(i) for i in y]
predict_val = [int(i) for i in y_pred]
confusion = confusion_matrix(true_val, predict_val)
np.savetxt('confusion_matrix.txt', confusion, delimiter=',')
```

Right now I get a matrix like this:

```
[[0 2]
[0 2]]
```

but say my labels are named "1" and "3"

I would like to get:

```
   1  3
1  0  2
3  0  2
```

Is there any library that would do something like this or do I need to do it by hand in the array

Answer (score 1):

Pandas does the job !

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'1' : pd.Series([0,0], index=[1,3]),
     '3' : pd.Series([2,2], index=[1,3])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

Comment: thank you. But I still need to manually put in each of my labels and the series associated with them.  I wanted to use the confusion matrix calculated and print it neatly to a file with the labels and the ability use use the code with different datasets which would have different labels and data.

Comment: print(pd.DataFrame(yourArray, index = ["1", "3"], names = ["1","3"]) )

Comment: print(pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix, index = true_val, names = true_val) )
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'

Comment: typo correct: print(pd.DataFrame(confusion, index = true_val, names = true_val) )
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'